# Generating functions of real-rooted polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Suppose $f_n(t)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial. Let $F(t,u) = \sum_n f_n(t)u^n$.

What conditions on $F(t,u)$ tell us that the $f_n(t)$ are real-rooted? Similarly, are there any conditions on $F(t,u)$ that would imply the $f_n(t)$ are an interlacing family, i.e. $f_j(t)$ interlaces $f_{j+1}(t)$?

The motivation for this question comes from the fact that many classic families of orthogonal polynomials have nice generating functions of two variables. The particular polynomials I am studying may not be orthogonal, but do appear to display these similar properties.

Comment: Many of the classical families arise where $f_n$ is the $n$th deriviative of some function, dividing by that function. We can express this as a differential equation for $F$. This sort of differential equation might imply the interlacing property, and it's possible that interlacing plus control on degrees gives real-rootedness.

Comment: You may find the following paper relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00209